# Log PID and TCP Listen

Tags: process, logs, tcp

I'm trying find, how can I log all process activites, for logging all TCP Listen syscalls. System is linux.

My main problem, I need do some logging for passive FTP connections, but with time occurence, pid of process and fresh opened listening port. That listenings are opened ad hoc, and life cycle is very short. Very often it is less than 1 second, then netstat is unusable in that scenario.

I think that logging will be usable for other cases.

Comment: `auditd` can log syscalls.